# Visual Inventory

Tags: javascript, css, image

I need to create a visual representation of database information. My exact situation is I am in a large organization that does HW and SW audits. I was wondering if I could program a website to pull information from a database and display it after being requested by clicking on an icon (a desk). The website would basically be floor plans with items being organized by desk (number of computers, software, etc.). I think I can figure out the SQL associations I just need to know the best place to start for having either links behind a floor plan (in pdf or jpg format I guess) or drawing the desk icons through programming. I'm a fairly inexperienced E-3 and this is a long term tasking that I need direction with. Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

I currently don't have any code to offer for this, since the only information I have is that I am to do this using Adobe Dreamweaver, which plays nicely with CF, Java, CSS, and HTML. I'm just getting a sense check of what I can do with my resources (cannot use anything Open Source sadly)

Comment: Yes, you can pull data with a website, likely using an AJAX request. Without code or a general idea of what you're looking for though, we can't really help much here. Please provide some sort of code that we can start from.

Comment: Start somewhere with basic web application stack include `jquery` and you can design your floor layout in a html and bind events on to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, without a place to start from you are basically asking us to build your website.

I have provided a sample way to pull data externally. **If you want additional clarification, please let me know what server-side code you are using (ie, RUBY, JAVA, PYTHON, PHP, etc)**

Best of luck!

### Here is an example of how to pull JSON data with a javascript AJAX call.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/YUWB2/302/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" class="list" value="click me"></input>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var echo = function(dataPass) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: dataPass,
        cache: false,
        success: function(json) {
            alert("UID=" + json.uid + "\nName=" + json.value);
        }
    });
};

$('.list').live('click', function() {
    $.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/uid/12345/value/nicholas_hazel", function(data) {
        var json = {
            json: JSON.stringify(data),
            delay: 1
        };
        echo(json);
    });
});
```

#### Learn more here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: I'm guessing if I wanted another window to popup with a predefined format I would input that in the "type" section of my echo variable? Thank you very much though I didn't know about the ajax function and it looks like a good place to start. I love learning java.

Comment: Maybe mention also about using a back-end language like PHP or JSP in conjunction with AJAX to get the data from an SQL Database or say that this will work specifically with JSON.

Comment: You're pulling `JSON` data with `AJAX` (through JavaScript), not `AJAX` data with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @zero298. And the question is quite ambiguous, so I believe I'm done here, as we could go in circles all day without a more specific question.